# PHP file not picking up $POST parameter from JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, post

Thank you very much for your help. I have the following file. The two alerts in the jquery event listener both work, but not the one inside the if (isset) block, as it is posting to itself. Thank you very much! I have abbreviated the code, everything is inside its proper tag.

```
    <?php session_start();
    include("config.php");



$myID = $_POST['chatid'];
$_SESSION['chateeID'] = $myID;


        
  if(isset($_POST['inputmessage'])) {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("got in here");</script>';
      
      $sMessage = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['inputmessage']);
      if ($sMessage != '') {

          


          $sql = "INSERT INTO chatmessages (user_one_id, user_two_id, mymessage, action_user_id)
          VALUES ('$user1', '$user2', '$sMessage', '$action_user_id')";
          
          
          // Perform a query, check for error
          
          
          if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
              echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("'.mysqli_error($con).'");</script>';
              
          }
      }
      
  }


<script>
  $('#ChatInputBox').keydown(function (e) {
      var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
      var txt = $("#ChatInputBox").val();
      
      if (keyCode == 13 && txt!="") {
        alert("txt is: "+txt);
        $.post("inserttochat.php", { inputmessage: txt }, function(result){
          alert("got to callback!");
        });
          
      }
      
  });


</script>
```

I did this exactly the same way on another page but cannot find the discrepancy here.

Comment: have you tried checking if you successfully receive the posted data? try `echo $_POST['inputmessage'];` in your inserttochat.php to see if it is defined

Comment: Is the PHP code in your question within the `inserttochat.php` script? If so, are you expecting the `<script>` blocks to be evaluated as part of the AJAX request?

Comment: btw you dont output values with `<script type="text/javascript">alert...`, instead pass it back as json, text or xml. To make it execute them scripts your need .html() not another alert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After setting up your code on my development system I discovered that the short piece of script your PHP code is sending is being sent correctly, and being received correctly but not being executed by the jQuery AJAX code.

If you want that alert to show up in your page you need to place it in an HTML element

```
 <div id="response"></div>
```

then

```
        $.post("inserttochat.php", { inputmessage: txt }, function(result){
          alert("got to callback!");
          $("response").html(result);
        });
```

A better way to do this is to echo some sort of status as a JSON object, then unpack that into an `alert` in Javascript.

```
echo json_encode((object)['status'=>'ok', 'msg'=>'All good']);
```

then

```
    $.post("inserttochat.php", { inputmessage: txt }, function(result){
      alert("Response: "+result.status+', '+result.msg);
    },'json');
```

Note the `json` datatype added to the `POST` request<sup>*</sup>.

- A better approach here is to standardise all your responses as JSON, and then add `header("Content-type: application/json");` at the top of your PHP files. This will tell jQuery what the data is, rather than you having to force the issue in the browser.

Comment: Thank you very much, very well explained--now I understand